# How to access a button using its name as a string in a for loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to access a button in a for loop but it's Name has to be changed.

Ex:

- There are a number of buttons whose Names are bt1,bt2,bt3,...bt25.
- I'm using a for loop in my code for certain purpose to disable or enable those buttons.
- Can I use a for loop to do this??

Like:

```
for(int i =1;i<25;i++)
{
    "bt"+"i".Enable = True;
}
```

How cam I make the string as a control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for(int i =1;i<25;i++)
{
    this.Controls["bt"+ i.ToString()].Enable = True;
}
```

VB (using code converter):

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 24
    Me.Controls("bt" & i.ToString()).Enable = [True]
Next
```

Comment: I don't know VB syntax but by code conversion it become:            For i As Integer = 1 To 24
 Me.Controls("bt" & i.ToString()).Enable = [True]
Next

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line with LINQ

```
Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(b => b.Enabled = false);
```

VB (also via converter)

```
Controls.OfType(Of Button)().ToList().ForEach(Function(b) InlineAssignHelper(b.Enabled, False))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code :

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is Button)
                {
                    ctrl.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
```

if its inside any container control , then try this :

```
foreach (Control Cntrl in this.Pnl.Controls)
            {
                if (Cntrl is Panel)
                {
                    foreach (Control C in Cntrl.Controls)
                        if (C is Button)
                        {
                            C.Enabled = true;
                        }
                }
            }
```

if want to implement in VB, then try this :

```
For Each Cntrl As Control In Me.Pnl.Controls
    If TypeOf Cntrl Is Panel Then
        For Each C As Control In Cntrl.Controls
            If TypeOf C Is Button Then
                C.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i =1;i<=25;i++)
{
    this.Controls["bt"+ i].Enable = True;
 //Or
    //yourButtonContainerObject.Controls["bt"+ i].Enable = True;
    // yourButtonContainerObject may be panel1, pane2 or Form, Depends where
   // your buttons are added. 'this' can be used in case of 'Form' only
}
```

Above code is valid only if you really have 25 buttonns and named as bt1,bt2,bt3...,bt25

```
       foreach (Control ctrl in yourButtonContainerObject.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is Button)
            {
                ctrl.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Above code is better if you want to enable all the buttons in a particular container (Form or panel etc).